# enable jqueryUI slider on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, onclick, slider

Im trying to enable the slider when the checkbox is checked!

the html:

```
  <label for="zerovalueback">Zero Back</label>
    <input id="zerovalueback" type="checkbox" name="zerovalueback">
    <div id="slider"></div>
    <div class="sliderValues">
        <span class="leftVal">
        </span>
         = = = 
        <span class="rightVal">
        </span>
    </div>
```

the script:

```
  jQuery.noConflict(); 
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

            jQuery('body').on('click', '#zerovalueback', function() {

            var status = jQuery(this).prop("checked");      console.log(status);
            if (status == 'true') {

                jQuery( "#slider" ).slider({
                range : "max",
                    min : 1,
                    max : 10,
                    value : 6,
                    slide: function(event,val){
                        jQuery('.leftVal').text(val.value);
                    } 
                 }); 
             };
         });
    });
```

Everything is linked correctly, because If I call simply the slider before the on(click) function it works.

Does anybody have idea how to solve this?

Comment: Try `jQuery(this).is(":checked");`

Comment: You have right, the if statement was not correct it should be if( status === true ){} and now it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The if statement was not correct, advice from @DontVoteMeDown was helpfull, 
it should be

```
if (status === true) {

                jQuery( "#slider" ).slider({
                range : "max",
                    min : 1,
                    max : 10,
                    value : 6,
                    slide: function(event,val){
                        jQuery('.leftVal').text(val.value);
                    } 
                 }); 
             }
```

Answer (score 1):

If your need is to enable disable jQuery. There are methods called enable() and disable(). you can find more info [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#method-disable).

To disable slider you can use `jQuery( "#slider" ).slider('disable');` and to enable slider you can use `jQuery( "#slider" ).slider('enable')`

You can find the working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CCCP9/2/)